# php mysqli return different number of rows compared to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm writing a complicated database query using PHP and MySQLi.

```
   $SQLstring = "
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Index`, `Type`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `acronym`, `ShiftIndex`, `TaskName`, `Text` FROM `shiftentry` 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `shiftIndex`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `Status` FROM `shiftreports`) `shiftreports` on `ShiftReport` = `shiftIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `siteIndex`, `acronym` FROM `sites`) `sites` ON `Site` = `siteIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `taskIndex`, `TaskName` FROM `tasks`) `tasks` on `Status` = `taskIndex`) AS a
        WHERE `Type` < '4' ".$searchstring."

        UNION

        SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Index`, `Type`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `acronym`, `ShiftIndex`, `TaskName`, `process`.`Text` AS `Text` FROM `shiftentry` 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `shiftIndex`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `Status` FROM `shiftreports`) `shiftreports` on `ShiftReport` = `shiftIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `siteIndex`, `acronym` FROM `sites`) `sites` ON `Site` = `siteIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `taskIndex`, `TaskName` FROM `tasks`) `tasks` on `Status` = `taskIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `statusIndex`, `process`, `progress`, `Comment` FROM `site-status`) `site-status` on `shiftentry`.`Text` = `statusIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `processIndex`, `Processname` AS `Text` FROM `process`) `process` on `process` = `processIndex`) AS b
        WHERE `Type` = '4' ".$searchstring."

        UNION

        SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Index`, `Type`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `acronym`, `ShiftIndex`, `TaskName`, `site-status`.`Text` AS `Text` FROM `shiftentry` 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `shiftIndex`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `Status` FROM `shiftreports`) `shiftreports` on `ShiftReport` = `shiftIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `siteIndex`, `acronym` FROM `sites`) `sites` ON `Site` = `siteIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `taskIndex`, `TaskName` FROM `tasks`) `tasks` on `Status` = `taskIndex`
        INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `statusIndex`, `process`, `progress`, `Comment` AS `Text` FROM `site-status`) `site-status` on `shiftentry`.`Text` = `statusIndex`) AS c
        WHERE `Type` = '4' ".$searchstring."

        ORDER BY `Date` DESC;";
    echo $SQLstring;
    $shiftentries=mysqli_query($conn, $SQLstring); 
    echo mysqli_num_rows($shiftentries);

    while($shiftentry = mysqli_fetch_array($shiftentries)) {
       ...
    }
```

The php is printing the SQL string in the very end. When I take exactly this string and copy&paste it to the phpMyAdmin SQL input field it will return a single result line

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Index`, `Type`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `acronym`, `ShiftIndex`, `TaskName`, `Text` FROM `shiftentry` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `shiftIndex`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `Status` FROM `shiftreports`) `shiftreports` on `ShiftReport` = `shiftIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `siteIndex`, `acronym` FROM `sites`) `sites` ON `Site` = `siteIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `taskIndex`, `TaskName` FROM `tasks`) `tasks` on `Status` = `taskIndex`) AS a WHERE `Type` < '4' AND `Text` LIKE '%matching%' UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Index`, `Type`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `acronym`, `ShiftIndex`, `TaskName`, `process`.`Text` AS `Text` FROM `shiftentry` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `shiftIndex`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `Status` FROM `shiftreports`) `shiftreports` on `ShiftReport` = `shiftIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `siteIndex`, `acronym` FROM `sites`) `sites` ON `Site` = `siteIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `taskIndex`, `TaskName` FROM `tasks`) `tasks` on `Status` = `taskIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `statusIndex`, `process`, `progress`, `Comment` FROM `site-status`) `site-status` on `shiftentry`.`Text` = `statusIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `processIndex`, `Processname` AS `Text` FROM `process`) `process` on `process` = `processIndex`) AS b WHERE `Type` = '4' AND `Text` LIKE '%matching%' UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT `Index`, `Type`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `acronym`, `ShiftIndex`, `TaskName`, `site-status`.`Text` AS `Text` FROM `shiftentry` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `shiftIndex`, `Date`, `User`, `Site`, `Status` FROM `shiftreports`) `shiftreports` on `ShiftReport` = `shiftIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `siteIndex`, `acronym` FROM `sites`) `sites` ON `Site` = `siteIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `taskIndex`, `TaskName` FROM `tasks`) `tasks` on `Status` = `taskIndex` INNER JOIN (SELECT `Index` AS `statusIndex`, `process`, `progress`, `Comment` AS `Text` FROM `site-status`) `site-status` on `shiftentry`.`Text` = `statusIndex`) AS c WHERE `Type` = '4' AND `Text` LIKE '%matching%' ORDER BY `Date` DESC;
```

[phpMyAdmin query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRwA7.png)

The php mysqli_query unfortunately returns zero lines for exactly the same query string.

```
echo mysqli_num_rows($shiftentries);
```

returns 0 and no data is displayed. This is an example where the query should just return a single entry when the keyword I'm searching for is "matching". In case I use different keywords it will return multiple lines but always one line less than phpMyAdmin.

It's strange! Do you have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: if it's the exact same query, it won't return different results. Try checking the $searchstring content

Comment: That's exaclty what I do. I print the content of the $SQLstring and copy&paste it to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You sure it's the same database connection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query you need to remove `caracter and replace` with ' caracter for as action and turn type>'4' to type>4  and make sure $searchstring have a and  in first:

```
$SQLstring = "
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT Index, Type, Date, User, Site, acronym, ShiftIndex, TaskName, Text FROM shiftentry 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'shiftIndex', Date, User, Site, Status FROM shiftreports) shiftreports on ShiftReport = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'siteIndex', acronym FROM sites) sites ON Site = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'taskIndex', TaskName FROM tasks) tasks on Status = Index) AS a
    WHERE Type < 4 ".$searchstring."

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM (SELECT Index, Type, Date, User, Site, acronym, ShiftIndex, TaskName, process.Text AS Text FROM shiftentry 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'shiftIndex', Date, User, Site, Status FROM shiftreports) shiftreports on ShiftReport = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'siteIndex', acronym FROM sites) sites ON Site = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'taskIndex', TaskName FROM tasks) tasks on Status = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'statusIndex', process, progress, Comment FROM site-status) site-status on shiftentry.Text = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'processIndex', Processname AS Text FROM process) process on process = Index) AS b
    WHERE Type = 4 ".$searchstring."

    UNION

    SELECT * FROM (SELECT Index, Type, Date, User, Site, acronym, ShiftIndex, TaskName, site-status.Text AS 'Text' FROM shiftentry 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'shiftIndex', Date, User, Site, Status FROM shiftreports) shiftreports on ShiftReport = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'siteIndex', acronym FROM sites) sites ON Site = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'taskIndex', TaskName FROM tasks) tasks on Status = Index
    INNER JOIN (SELECT Index AS 'statusIndex', process, progress, Comment AS Text FROM site-status) site-status on shiftentry.Text = Index) AS c
    WHERE Type= 4 ".$searchstring."

    ORDER BY Date DESC;";
echo $SQLstring;
$shiftentries=mysqli_query($conn, $SQLstring); 
echo mysqli_num_rows($shiftentries);

while($shiftentry = mysqli_fetch_array($shiftentries)) {
   ...
}
```